# How to hide div slowly in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two `div` when I click button to close the `div`. second `div` moves upward I just want to do this slowly. I try to use transition effect but cant do it any help? thanks in advance.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssZXA/)

Comment: as you can tell by the number of answers - this is popular and easy to find info on - try google first before stack overflow - i found 25 different articles on it by typingg your question into google first! :-P - btw i am not you -1 butr that is probably why you got it!!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ssZXA/190/

Comment: I have updated my answer as you also want to move your another div slowly.

Comment: i dont know why but i really didnt find it on google so i ask it here. is it my foult :P ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ssZXA/185/

read the documentation about [`.hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/)
the first argument is "duration"

You can use `$("#notice").hide('slow');`

Answer (score 8):

use `fadeOut`

```
$( "#closebutton" ).click(function(event)
 {
    $("#notice").fadeOut('slow');  //OR fadeOut('10000') time is in milliseconds
 });
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/somnath_k/ssZXA/186/)

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
  $("#notice").slideToggle();
```

or

```
 $("#notice").fadeOut();
```

In Place of

```
 $("#notice").hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Plz try this:

```
$("#notice").hide("slow");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
$("#notice").hide('fade');
```

or

```
$("#notice").hide('slideUp');
```

instead of `$("#notice").hide();`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ssZXA/183/)

Comment: ok its fine now much better but i also want second div to move slow

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

```
<body>
  <div id="myDiv" style="width:200px;height:150px;background-color:red;">
  This is the div that will fade out, slide up, then be removed from the DOM.
  </div>
  <input id="myButton" type="button" value="Fade" />
</body>

$(function() {
     $("#myButton").click(function() {
         $("#myDiv").fadeTo("slow", 0.00, function(){
             $(this).slideUp("slow", function() {
                 $(this).remove();
             });
         });

     });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/avebe/16)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $("#notice").hide('fade','slow');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ssZXA/187/)

or

```
 $("#notice").hide('fade',5000);
```

5000- indicates it will take 5seconds to hide. you can give any value.

Syntax:
      **$("selector").hide('type',time);**

Answer (score 1):

Just apply `slow` on `hide` function and I customized your code as follows:

```
$("#closebutton").button({
    icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-close"
    },
    text: false
}).click(function(event) {
    $("#notice").hide("slow");
});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/ssZXA/189/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

    $(this).html('&laquo;'); 

    $('.slider-arrow').click(function(){    

        var x = $(".slider-arrow").offset();
        if (x.left == "308") 
        {     
            $( ".slider-arrow, .panel").animate({left: "-=300"}, 700);
        }
        else
        {
            $( ".slider-arrow, .panel").animate({left: "+=300"}, 700);    
        }
    });    
});
```